# I have a Python API and some example projects built from that API. How do I structure this using packages, to eventually distribute?

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi, python-packaging

I have an API written in Python that exists in two files as seen in the below file structure (`game_api.py` and `drift.py`), and two projects written utilising that API that I want to provide as examples in my project.

I am having trouble understanding how to structure these files using packages.

Current file structure:

```
game_api/
├── __init__.py
├── game_api.py
├── drift.py
├── examples
│   ├── cli_game
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── cli_game.py
│   │   ├── colouring.py
│   │   └── keyboard.py
│   └── gui_game
│       └── gui_game.py
```

When building the API and examples I had all the files in one directory and it was very messy.

I've tried to turn the folders `game_api` and `cli_game` and `gui_game` into packages, however I can't import `game_api` into the two example projects.

In `cli_game.py` for example I have tried `from game_api import *` to no avail.

If I don't put all the example files in the same directory as the game_api, then how can I keep things organised and in packages?

I'm not sure how I should structure it, and I need to get this right before I can start to work out how to package it all up to put on github/pypi so that other people can use the API.

edit:  I have seen answers to similar questions that use os file import redirects, and this seems a bit hacky/messy. Surely there is a proper way to structure this kind of scenario. It seems like it should be simple enough.

Comment: do you have a public github repo ?

Comment: @cizario no not at the moment, sorry if that is what i implied. i meant that i wanted to prepare my file structure to eventually upload publically for other people to download and use

Answer (score 0):

below how i usually structure my python packages:

```
game/
  .. .github 
  .. .vscode
  .. docs

  .. exemples/
     .. cli/
        .. __init__.py
        .. cli.py
        .. colouring.py
        .. keyboard.py
     .. gui/
        .. __init__.py
        .. gui.py

  .. src/
     .. game/
        .. __init__.py
        .. api.py
        .. drift.py

  .. tests
  .. venv
  .. .editconfig
  .. .gitignore
  .. .readthedocs.yml
  .. LICENSE
  .. MANIFEST.in
  .. pyproject.toml
  .. README.rst
  .. setup.cfg
  .. setup.py (optional as per officiel docs)
```

#### MANIFEST.in

```
# https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/
graft src/game
graft tests
global-exclude __pycache__
global-exclude *.py[cod]
```

#### pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
# https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#setup-cfg-only-projects
requires = [
  "setuptools >= 58",
  "wheel"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

#### setup.cfg

```
# https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html
[metadata]
name = game
version = attr: game.__version__
description = [..]
long_description = file: README.rst
long_description_content_type = text/x-rst
author = [..]
author_email = [..]
# maintainer =
# maintainer_email =
license = [..]
license_file = LICENSE
# license_files = LICENSES/*
url = [..]
download_url = [..]
project_urls =
    Documentation = [..]
    Issue Tracker = [..]
    Source Code = [..]
keywords = [..]
classifiers =
    Development Status :: 1 - Planning
    Framework :: Django
    Framework :: Django :: 3.0
    Framework :: Django :: 3.1
    Framework :: Django :: 3.2
    Intended Audience :: Developers
    License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License
    Operating System :: OS Independent
    Programming Language :: Python
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only
platforms = any

[options]
python_requires = >=3.8
install_requires =
    [..]
packages = find:
package_dir =
    = src
include_package_data = True
zip_safe = False

[options.packages.find]
where = src

[options.extras_require]
# tests =
#   pytest
#   pytest-cov

# code =
#   flake8
```

#### `src/game/__init__.py`

```
VERSION = (0, 0, 1, 'dev0')
__version__ = '.'.join(map(str, VERSION))

[..]
```

#### build nd publish

if you are on windows and you want to build and publish your package

```
pip install build wheel
py -m build -n  # don't forget '-n' flage to force using your project venv
pip install -e .  # for editable mode, it will create  symbol link to the package


# if everything is ok then pulish it on pypi
pip install twine
py -m twine upload dist/*
```

now, under `exemples` folder, you can do `from game.api import *`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I am still stuck on an initial step however. I followed your file structure and now have the following:

https://imgur.com/a/3r1saaY

I then defined a simple hello() func in api.py, and then tried to import it in cli.py with `from game.api import *` and then call the function.

When I run it with `python3 cli.py` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: no module called 'game'`.

Do I need to follow all of the configuration steps you listed to get this import working, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: i guess you need to `cd exemples/cli/` then try `python3 cli.py`

Comment: I have just tried that however I still get the same result? Am I still doing something wrong? https://imgur.com/a/1OIM1Dn

Comment: i guess you didn't build the package, head over the **build nd publish** section obove, let me know

Comment: If i just want to build my package locally and not publish, which commands do I use? is it just the middle two? also I am on linux

Comment: ok, run those commands (or linux equivalent) `pip install build wheel` then `py -m build -n` and then `pip install -e .` and everythying should work locally.